# What's the correct way to atomically exchange two unsigned 32-bit variables (ULONG)?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2012, atomic-swap

I found the [InterlockedExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which allows me to exchange two **signed** 32-bit variables (LONG).

But, what is the correct way to atomically exchange two **unsigned** 32-bit variables (ULONG) under Windows?

I do not see an obvious way to do that using the functions provided by Microsoft.

(Considering that Microsoft also tells me that the result of converting unsigned integers to signed integers is [implementation-defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9s326kw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in some cases.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a type-cast:

```
ULONG value1, value2;
InterlockedExchange((LPLONG)&value2, (LONG)value1);
```

Comment: As I said (see link above), the `(LONG)` cast is implementation-defined for results which cannot be represented. So how do you know what happens, if `value1` is e.g. equal to `4000000000u` which does not fit into a `LONG`?

Comment: If you hadn´t ignored the other answer here, 3 minutes before, you would know why you did get that wrong...it´s true, even if i have not that much rep

Comment: @user3465629 The implementation-defined behavior is documented: [LONG to ULONG preserves the bit pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbfs6fd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The alternative is to force the bit pattern to be preserved manually, instead of relying on the compiler to do it: `InterlockedExchange((LPLONG)&value2, *((LPLONG)&value1));`

Comment: @Raymond Chen. That's the part of information I was missing. Thanks a lot! I would add that especially for the *other* conversion, from `ULONG` to `LONG`, the bit pattern is also preserved.

Answer (score 0):

In your link, casting a unigned something to types of different sizes
(and/or floting point stuff) is explained.
Casting only between signed and unigned of the same type
should be possible without any problems.